# Make plural when quantity is greater than 1

Tags: pluralize

i already have this code but it does not work as expected.

the word "piece" should be changed to "pieces" when the quantity is greater than 1.

```
<span class="counter b">2 <span id="unitpcs"></span></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

var q = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var a = myFunction(q.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("unitpcs").innerHTML = x;

function myFunction() {
if (a > 1) {
        x = "pieces";
    } else {
        x = "piece";
    }
}
</script>
```

Currently, when the quantity is equal to one (1), the result is correct: 1 piece.

If the quantity becomes two (2), the result is not correct: 2 piece
The correct output should be "2 pieces".

Any solution is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please state your question a bit clearer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For example: when the quantity is one (1), the output should be 1 item. then, if the quantity is greater than 1, e.g. 2 items, 3 items, and so on.

Comment: Hi @jaidsis, please update your question with this comment. Also try to explain what is the current behavior and what you would expect instead.

Comment: Hi @toti08, i already updated the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to specify `a` as the parameter of `myFunction()`.
2. You overlooked that `q` is an array of two `span` elements.
3. You neglected to convert the `.innerHTML` to a number.

```html
<span class="counter b">2 <span id="unitpcs"></span></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var q = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
myFunction(parseFloat(q[0].innerHTML)); // first span, convert to number
document.getElementById("unitpcs").innerHTML = x;

function myFunction(a) {
if (a > 1) {
        x = "items";
    } else {
        x = "item";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Armali, a million thanks for your answer. it solved the problem.